Wine winecfg 0080:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow
I use notepad++ under Ubuntu 22.04 on daily base, but wanted to increase menu font size
I try to use winecfg to affect DPI parameter
I use laptop with Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10310U CPU and internal graphics
During run of winecfg I faced:
$ winecfg
0080:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0080:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
0080:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
00c8:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
00c8:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
00c8:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0080:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
00c8:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
00c8:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0080:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0110:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0110:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.

not sure which driver is missing

$ echo $DISPLAY
:0

export WINEDLLOVERRIDES="winex11.drv=b"
winecfg
gave same errors
